# Possible to save type in object?

Tags: typescript, types

The below example gives the correct calculation, but for some reason `p.calcPrice` is a string. I would expect that it is a number, as `.toFixed()` doesn't make sense in a string.

Whenever I use `p.calcPrice`, do I then have to cast it with `+p.calcPrice`, or can I have TypeScript treat as a number, so I don't have to cast it?

```
p.calcPrice = (
  price *
  +p.amount *
  (1 - pD / 100) *
  (1 - mD / 100)
).toFixed(2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`toFixed` returns a string, you have to cast it manually.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed#return_value

one way for casting would be to wrap it in Number:

```js
p.calcPrice = Number((price * +p.amount * (1 - pD / 100) * (1 - mD / 100)).toFixed(2));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could rewrite it like this so it will already be cast to a number because `toFixed` returns a string. Mind the `+` before the clause.:

```js
p.calcPrice = +(
  price *
  +p.amount *
  (1 - pD / 100) *
  (1 - mD / 100)
).toFixed(2);
```